# Sin conexión LAN WAMP

Tags: apache

He montado un servidor en WAMP, de forma local funciona de maravilla, pero no me puedo conectar por LAN, me avienta el siguiente error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /oros/index.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) PHP/5.6.19 Server at 172.20.106.31 Port 8080
```

Ya le puse PutOnline, he seguido sin mentir como 20 tutoriales pero no logro conseguir el cometido. Tengo este código en httpd.conf

```
    ServerSignature On
ServerTokens Full
ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.18"
Define APACHE24 Apache2.4
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.19/php5apache2_4.dll"
<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
ServerAdmin wampserver@otomatic.net
ServerName 172.20.106.31:8080
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
HostnameLookups Off
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/wamp/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>
<Directory "c:/wamp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile off
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

He borrado los Module para no hacer el tema tan amplio. Ya desactivé por completo el firewall, el antivirus y he dado como sitio de confiaza la IP en la máquina por la cuál quiero ingresar.

La IP que estoy poniendo en la otra PC es

```
172.20.106.31:8080/oros/index.php
```

El apache_error me avienta lo siguiente

```
[Tue Aug 09 13:55:44.107966 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 4176:tid 884] [client 172.20.106.113:57691] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/Oros/index.php
[Tue Aug 09 13:55:44.515936 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 4176:tid 884] [client 172.20.106.113:57691] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://172.20.106.31:8080/oros/index.php
```

Creo que si esta alcanzando el destino sin problemas pero por alguna razón esta negando el acceso :(
Ayuda compatriotas, qué estoy haciendo mal.
¿Me faltará un Alias o VirtualHost?

Comment: Creo que ya está de más, ya jaló, únicamente creé un Alias y me dió acceso.
Gracias por su lectura, doy por cerrado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar especificar los permisos para ese directorio en particular. Coloca un archivo `.htaccess` en `C:/wamp/www/Oros/`:

#### .htaccess

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/oros/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> **Nota**
>   Tal vez sea importante que cambies la ruta de *Oros* a **oros**. Aunque en Windows no parece ser relevante, en otros sistemas operativos, el directorio *"Oros"* (con mayúscula) es diferente a *oros* (con minúscula). Y lo mismo pasa con los archivos.